# Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device, file is corrupted

Tags: genymotion

I have successfully installed Genymotion and Virtualbox ,but not able to create virtual devices. virtual device is complete download but file is corrupted, not only one but all

Comment: I am having the same problem. What is your OS? I'm having this problem with Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @oliverdrummond still having this issue in 2016? check my answer below

Answer (score 6):

If your are using Ubuntu, I just found the soluction!
Run Genymotion as a SUDO. To do that, open your terminal, go to the Genymotion folder and type:

> sudo ./genymotion

Now go and download your Virtual Machine!

Hope it works for you too

Comment: WOW! Glad to hear that this is still relevant 10 years later :)

Answer (score 1):

I am running genymotion on Mac OS X 10.9.2 and must run Genymotion via sudo.

I created a bash script that I run:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/genymotion
```

I've named the script `run-genymotion.sh`.

Make sure to `chmod +x ./run-genymotion.sh` so it is executable.

Then `./run-genymotion.sh` to execute the script via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in some company and your company has cyberroam configured on it, i.e., if there is restricted access for downloading, then you just need to enable downloading on your system. As I was also having this issue, I had downloaded Genymotion(no restriction occur using 'https') but at the time of downloading for the virtual device its showing message for corrupt files, so just enabled download rights from network admin, then it started to download. I had done full installation process 2 times and both the times the first full download(both times) also showed the same 'corrupt files' message but the second download(both times) succeeded.

Check, in case, if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you've ran genymotion for the first time as root.

fix it this way :

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Genymobile
```

and now try again to install a virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did mine. Every single virtual device I downloaded in Genymotion, I was told it is corrupted. What is wrong with Genymotion?

Well, TL;DR, locate the downloaded file, open and run with Virtualbox first time, and come back to Genymotion to run it.

- Via nautilus, or your file manager, go to `~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova`
- Double click on the `.ova` file to open in VirtualBox (or right click and Open with VirtualBox)
- You should see the genymotion virtual device listed in the list of Virtual devices in your VirtualBox
- Try starting the genymotion virtual device in VirtualBox. You should end up with a terminal prompt after boot.
- Do `reboot -p shutdown` to close the terminal
- Open genymotion (I do mine as `~/Developments/Genymotion/genymotion/genymotion`)
- You should see a virtual device listed in Genymotion
- Start it, and you're done.

Comment: I followed this after none of the other solutions (such as reinstalling geny and VB) worked for me, and indeed starting the box from virtualbox gives me a terminal prompt, but it gets stuck at "`Waiting for eth0 link..`" so I can't actually close the terminal with a command (powered it off virtually) and opening Genymotion doesn't seem to let it detect anything - it doesn't get listed

Answer (score 0):

You may execute genymotion using `sudo` or change file permissions of genymotion and it's files with:

```
chown -R username:username /path/to/genymotion
```

Also change file permissions of the deployed images and cached ova files which are probably in `~/.Genymobile/Genymotion`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using genymotion on windows and had the same problem.
I've just changed Virtual Prices Path from C drive to D drive (just another drive) and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for me:

1. clear cache file in genymotion settings/misc/clear cache
2. restart genymotion with admin privilleges